# how to implement logic operators in prolog

Tags: prolog, logical-operators

I want to define the logical operators not, or, and, nand, nor and xor in prolog

I have already tried this

```
and(A,B) :- A,B.
or(A,B) :- A;B.
nand(A,B) :- not(and(A,B)).
nor(A,B) :- not(or(A,B)).
xor(A,B) :- or(A,B), nand(A,B).
```

But I have to use the following facts:

```
opnot(Variable, Result).
opor(Variable1, Variable2, Restult).
opand(Variable1, Variable2, Restult).
opnand(Variable1, Variable2, Result).
opnor(Variable1, Variable2, Result).
opxor(Variable1, Variable2, Result).
```

Can you please help me write the rules?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use predicates you've already defined for accomplishing that.

`opand/3` and all the other predicates with arity 3 would be defined in the following way:

```
opand(Variable1, Variable2, Result) :- and(Variable1, Variable2) -> Result = true ; Result = false.
```

Definition of `opnot/2` would be a bit different:

```
opnot(Variable, Result) :- not(Variable) -> Result = true ; Result = false.
```

Comment: use of `->` for if-then-else logic in Prolog is always dubious at best . Better as two clauses ``
opand(Variable1, Variable2, true) :- and(Variable1, Variable2) .`` ``
opand(Variable1, Variable2, false) :- nand(Variable1, Variable2) .``